# display meteor aggregation Json data in google charts

Tags: meteor, google-visualization

Iam a newbie for meteor and google charts, want to display the google chart with meteor mongodb aggregate Json data. To start with i have a static json data but for some reason the google visulization datatable returning empty. the following is the Client.js code.

```
Template.GooglechartsPie.onRendered(function () {
    console.log("iam from render function")
        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: drawChart});

    function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = '[{"_id":"Household","totalAmount":520},{"_id":"Insurance","totalAmount":235},{"_id":"Family","totalAmount":1358},{"_id":"Utilities","totalAmount":5371.5},{"_id":"Automobile","totalAmount":500},{"_id":"Home Office","totalAmount":290},{"_id":"Travel","totalAmount":14},{"_id":"Food","totalAmount":303}]'

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    console.log("my data" + JSON.stringify(data))
     //returning my data"{\"cols\":[],\"rows\":[]}" -- not sure why no data here

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Googlechart'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should be formatted like this

```
{
"cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ],
"rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

So when you're trying to convert your JSON to a DataTable you're not getting any returns as it isn't correctly formatted. [More to read here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example#sampledatajson-file).

Try formatting your JSON like

```
var jsonData = {}
jsonData.cols = [
      {"label":"ID", "type":"string"},
      {"label":"Value", "type":"number"}
  ]
jsonData.rows = [
     {"c":[{"v":"Household"}, {"v":520}]},
     {"c":[{"v":"Insurance"}, {"v":200}]}
]
```